# How do I determine Data Load time for External tables?

Tags: oracle, external, oracle12c, data-dump

I am using Oracle DB 12c Enterprise Edition.

I have set up the file directory for the flat file (.csv) saved on my desktop. The external table is already created and data is being loaded directly to my external table set up in oracle.

It appears that the data import from .CSV --> External Table is a transparent process. How exactly do I determine how long it took to load all the data in .CSV flat file to external table?

My .CSV flat file has 150,000 records. The BADFILE and LOGFILE are produced but it does not provide a specific time on how long it took to load all the files.

Please help..

My goal is to determine if Loading Data via External Table is faster than SQL*LDR or Data Import Utility in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

The data is loaded from the external table every time you query it.  So one option would be to do a

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM your_external_table
```

and measuring the amount of time that requires.  If your intention is to load the data from the external table into the same staging table that you'd load with SQL*Loader, you could also measure the time required to do that `INSERT`.

Comment: hi, check create external table commads , there we can specify log files .     i guess log file could write the time taken for loading

Comment: @Ramki - I'm not sure how you'd derive the time taken to load data from the log file.  As the original poster points out, the log file doesn't provide that metric directly.  I suppose if the log file doesn't exist when you start the load you might be able to compare the file creation date and the last modified date to get a rough idea of when the load started and finished.  But I'm not at all certain how accurate that might be.

Comment: yes your right , i am also hinting log time only. But if we are loading to staging table then can't we measure time taken for  "Insert into My_stageTable ( select * from MY_externaltable );" form sqlplus  ; i saw now you also mention the same in your comment.

Comment: @JustinCave Isnt External Table separate from SQL*Loader?  I like your idea of comparing the file creation date and last modified date. There is a 14 seconds difference.

Comment: @MartinHuang - An external table (if you're using it to load a comma-separated data file) is just an alternate interface to SQL*Loader.  You're basically calling the same code.  Barring cases where there are architectural differences (i.e. using SQL*Loader to load a file on the client machine vs. using external tables to load a file on the server machine), it's unlikely that there will be persistent meaningful performance differences between the two.  If there are, you could almost certainly adjust the SQL*Loader parameters to get similar performance.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @JustinCave .. I just learnt that SQL*Loader is the same as external table.. Only thing is somehow, it is Read-only. I tried to insert/update/delete records in external table and got an "operation not supported" error. Has this got to do with the TYPE: ORACLE_LOADER when i declared in the Create Table [external table ] script. I will try to change the type to ORACLE_DATAPUMP. Read somewhere u can do a read and write on external table with that.

Comment: @MartinHuang - You can write to an `ORACLE_DATAPUMP` external table.  But then you're producing a file that only Oracle DataPump can read from.  You can't produce (or read from) a comma-separated data file using DataPump.  That's why I said the if you're using external tables to load a comma-separated file, it's just another interface to SQL*Loader.  It can also be another interface to DataPump if you're not working with comma-separated data files.